# How to create pop up message and update the inner text dynamically

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, alert

I want to create a pop up message and make the inner text changes according to some event, such as the displaying a timer !.

It's :  single message box with changing text

Comment: Do you mean have (potentially) several alerts that have custom text, of you do mean have a single alert with changing text? The latter would not be possible with Javascript (at least, not with the `alert` function).

Comment: @usernametbd yes, it's single alert with changing text

Comment: In that case, `alert` will not be able to handle this- you could create something that *looks* like an alert popup, but it'll be handled by the page, not the browser- so some functionality will be lost (like the alert being visible while changing tabs)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, a raw javascript confirm or alert box is not able to have dynamically updating text, due to the fact that the box itself is a blocking call. (No additional javascript will run until the box is closed).

Your best bet is to use an HTML styled popup box rather than a javascript window.alert or window.confirm

See here for an example: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog